# How can i convert ionic 3 to swift code ?

Tags: ionic3

I want to convert my ionic 3 code into swift code. is this possible in ionic 3

as per my knowledge, ionic 3 only converts code in objective c

Comment: Ionic only transpiles typescript to javascript and then packages web code with cordova binary. there is no conversion at all...

Comment: Hey Sergey Rudenko, Thanks for your reply